# Speeding up a parquet table in spark databricks

Tags: sql, databricks, parquet

I've got a table with several thousand rows, but I'm struggling with access. I've written out to the table using the below command, the table query needs to offer data quick access, but paritioning would not be appropriate because there is only one field needed in the query (i.e. an `id`).

Is there a way to add an index or transfer over an index from the pandas and then spark dataframe that was used to create the table?

```
df_spark.write.option('header','true').option("overwriteSchema", "true").saveAsTable(name="db.table", mode="overwrite")
```

Would delta as a `format` option give me a better chance of success as opposed to parquet?

Reading is the issue. With around a million rows, doing a simple look up is slow, taking a second or so, which is really rather too long. I'm assuming it is because `company_id` is not indexed.

`select * from db.table where company_id = 1234`

Is there a way of pushing an index down from the dataframe into the db? The only query is on the `company_id` so that is the field that needs to be indexed, but of course this is not suitable for paritioning!

Comment: "*I've got a table with several thousand rows*" "*With around a million rows*" Ok, which is it?

Comment: Bloom Filter Indexes can help with lookups

Comment: @Error_2646 Several Hundred Thousand and towards millions eventually.

Comment: Maybe Zorder on the column in your where can help. Please add an example of the SQL query you use on this table.

Comment: @ChenHirsh This is in the question now.

Comment: a million rows is a very low number ....

Comment: @MitchWheat Exactly which is why I'm surprised its so slow. I assume that there is no indexing possible whatsoever?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve better query performance when filtering a data table by a column, use zorder to order files by that column.

```
optimize db.table zorder by (company_id)
```

zorder is not an index, and cannot pull the relevant row directly. It helps Databricks to read only the relevant files (that contain that id), and by reading less data improves performance.

Optimize itself can also improve performance if you have a lot of small files. Optimize will merge them into larger files for better read performance.

Comment: This seemed to create a lot of files, but not performance increase. Is there no way to create an index?

Comment: There are no Indexes in Databricks